# Rails Active Record Associations between a registered user and unregistered one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two ***models*** one is `Resident` and other is `User`.`Residents`  are the people that resides in hostel,they have enrolled manually.And `Users` that have enrolled using our Application,But all the Residents are manually registered then we seed our database with them,we have stored info about them as long before they have registered in our website.but if they registered we have all info about then just need email more,How could we associate then in Rails.`User` have permit to all the stuff in our Website.while the `Residents` can only see it,not edit!

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: suggest me !what association I apply between two two models ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to restrict access depending on the type of permissions a person has. I would say the best solution for you is probably to use a Gem that handles this. There are several, CanCan is the one I usually use: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

With CanCan you have a file called ability where you can segment which types of users have access to specific resources.

Comment: I need a association between those two models not authorization !